# jQuery deferred not working on chrome and safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want `drawImage` on canvas tag and then save it again. And I use `deferred.done()` of jQuery.

Here is the code I use :

```
function save_submit() {
    LoadDraw().done(function(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById('touchpaint');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    });
var LoadDraw = function () {
    var r = $.Deferred();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('touchpaint');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageLoader = 'http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/3453/gokum.jpg';
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function (){
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    });
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    img.src = imageLoader;    
    r.resolve();
    return r;
  }
```

It works fine on Firefox. But does not work on Chrome and Safari. I am looking for help. Thank you.

Comment: `But does not work on Chrome and Safari` - could you be more specific? What is not working? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: After I painted on canvas. I want to save canvas + imageBackground. On firefox, I can save canvas + background. But on Chrome or Safari does not save the background. It does not report any errors. It's only save canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not using the Deferred correctly. The idea of a Deferred object is to resolve it  in some kind of callback function, not 'directly' after you create it.

In your case, you probably should resolve the deferred (r) in the $(img).load callback function:

```
var LoadDraw = function () {
    var r = $.Deferred();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('touchpaint');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageLoader = 'http://img262.imageshack.us/img262/3453/gokum.jpg';
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).load(function (){
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      r.resolve();
    });
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    img.src = imageLoader;    

    return r;
  }
```

Comment: The first, thank you so much. But, after fuction LoadDraw().done. I can't get canvas.toURLdata();

Comment: Why not? when the image is fully loaded you should be able to use the toURLdata function, right?

Comment: Right. I think so. I try loaded image to canvas. But function LoadDraw not run complete. Not done.There was an error with function DrawLoad.